# How can I use min-width 100% and still have expanding by content?

Tags: css, navigation, navbar, menubar

I have a menubar which is fine, but I want the dropdown menus to have a minimum width of 100% of the link item above it. It is easier illustrated with images:

This is fine:
[image: 1]

But I want this one to be at least 100% wide:
[image: 2]

What I don't want is for them to be exactly 100% wide. I know how to do that, but I've been struggling with making them all *at least* 100% wide for a long while, and I can't figure it out.

The main section of css I'm dealing with is the `#menu > ul > li > ul`. I have tried applying `min-width: 100%` to it, but they all just become exactly 100%. Why doesn't this work?

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jLLJu/1/) showing a live demo of my problem, and it includes all the css for the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That’ll need just a couple of small adjustments.

First of all, position your `li` relative, so that they explicitly become the anchor point for the sub-level `ul` (this is necessary, so that the `ul` can take their min-width from their parents):

```
#menu > ul > li {
    position:relative;
}
```

Second, position the `ul` to the left of their parent `li`, and give them a `min-width`:

```
#menu > ul > li > ul {
  left:0;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

Forbid the `a` elements inside the sub-level `ul` from breaking if the width of the element is not sufficient, by using the `white-space` property:

```
#menu > ul > li > ul > li > a {
    white-space:pre;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jLLJu/4/ (I added my modifications to the bottom of your CSS for clarity; feel free to move them up to where the rest of your formattings for the elements concerned are.)

Comment: Perfect, thanks! The `white-space: pre` is exactly what I was looking for.